# Split rows in a column and plot graph for a dataframe. Python

Tags: python, pandas

My data set contains the data of days and hrs

```
time slot              hr_slot       location_point
2019-01-21 00:00:00       0              34
2019-01-21 01:00:00       1              564
2019-01-21 02:00:00       2              448 
2019-01-21 03:00:00       3              46
.
.
.
.
2019-01-22 23:00:00       23             78
2019-01-22 00:00:00       0              34
2019-01-22 01:00:00       1              165
2019-01-22 02:00:00       2              65 
2019-01-22 03:00:00       3              156
.
.
.
.
2019-01-22 23:00:00       23             78
```

The data set conatins 7 days. that is 7*24 row. How to plot the graph for the dataset above.

```
hr_slot on the X axis : (0-23 hours)
loaction_point on Y axis : (location_point)
and each day should have different color on the graph: (Day1: color1, Day2:color2....)
```

Comment: I tried the basic one which plots all the days in x-axis and location points on y-axis.      ```dt =df.iloc[:,1:2]
dt.plot(figsize=(20, 10))```

Comment: I tried this but not able to divide according to the days. The graph is in single color and very clumsy ```dt.plot(x='hr_slot',y='location_point',figsize=(20, 10))```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider [pivoting](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) your data first:

```
# Create normalized date column
df['date'] = df['time slot'].dt.date.astype(str)

# Pivot
piv = df.pivot(index='hr_slot', columns='date', values='location_point')
piv.plot()
```

#### Update

To filter which dates are plotted, using `loc` or `iloc`:

```
# Exclude first and last day    
piv.iloc[:, 1:-1].plot()

# Include specific dates only
piv.loc[:, ['2019-01-21', '2019-01-22']].plot()
```

Alternate approach using [`pandas.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.crosstab.html) instead:

```
(pd.crosstab(df['hr_slot'],
             df['time slot'].dt.date,
             values=df['location_point'],
             aggfunc='sum')
 .plot())
```

Comment: @Krush23 happy to help :)

Comment: Is there a way to show graph for only specific date? 1)Like removing the first and last days. 2) Removing or plotting the first/last n days.

Comment: Yeh with usual filtering, `loc` or `iloc` i will update my answer

Comment: ```KeyError: "None of [Index(['2019-01-21', '2019-01-22'], dtype='object', name='date')] are in the [columns]"``` Error i got when tried to plot specific dates

Comment: This is because the column headers are actually stored as date objects. I had to update my answer for this issue, use `df['date'] = df['time slot'].dt.date.astype(str)`